# No me imprime por pantalla una sentencia SQL hecha desde Java

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que es una aplicacion para un concesionario de vehiculos, esta aplicacion va conectada a una base de datos mysql.

La aplicacion de java tiene que introducir y leer cosas de la base de datos, como por ejemplo cada vez que se hace una compra se registraria la compra y el coche se añadiria a nuestro stock actual de coches.

El problema que tengo es que no me imprime nada, lo que pretendo hacer es que me imprima la tabla coche de la base de datos, a ver si podeis ayudarme porque estoy bloqueadisimo, muchas gracias de antemano, soy un estudiante y soy nuevo en esto.

```
  package comunicacion;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class ComBD {
    private static final String CONTROLADOR ="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BDT_CONCESIONARIO";
    private static final String USUARIO ="root";
    private static final String CONTRASEÑA="root";

    static {
         try {
             Class.forName(CONTROLADOR);
         } 
         catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
             System.out.println("Error al cargar el controlador");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }



    public Connection Conectar() {
        Connection conexion = null;
        try {

            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USUARIO, CONTRASEÑA);
            System.out.println("Conexión OK");
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error en la conexion");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conexion;
    }




    void consultaCoche() {
        ComBD conexion = new ComBD();
        Connection cn= null;
        Statement stm = null;
        ResultSet respuesta = null;
        try {
            cn =conexion.Conectar();
            stm=cn.createStatement();
            respuesta = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM coche");
            while(respuesta.next()) {
                int numBastidor=respuesta.getInt(1);
                String color = respuesta.getString(2);
                int numAsientos=respuesta.getInt(3);
                int precio =respuesta.getInt(4);
                int codSerie= respuesta.getInt(5);
                String matricula =respuesta.getString(6);
                int numPuertas= respuesta.getInt(7);
                int capacidadMaletero = respuesta.getInt(8);
                System.out.println("Numero de bastidor: "+ numBastidor);
                System.out.println("Color: "+color);
                System.out.println("Numero de asientos: "+numAsientos);
                System.out.println("Precio: "+ precio+"€");
                System.out.println("Numero de serie: "+codSerie);
                System.out.println("Matricula: "+matricula);
                System.out.println("Numero de puertas: "+numPuertas);
                System.out.println("Capacidad del maletero: "+ capacidadMaletero);
            }
        }
    }
```

Creo que tengo mal el Statement pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: y donde queres que imprima todo eso? en la consola?

Comment: No sé si esto te resuelva el problema pero estás creando una instancia de `ComBD` y cuando llamas a `consultaCoche` estás creando otra instancia de `ComBD` para realizar la consulta. La lógica debería ser la siguiente: 1. Crear la instancia. 2. Conectar. 3. Con la misma instancia consultar. 4. Cerrar la conexión cuando ya no se necesita hacer más consultas. Una cosa más, ponle un `catch` a ese `try {...}` e imprime la excepción si se está dando alguna, eso te podría dar una idea de lo que está pasando.